# How does boost::bind pass arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I'm having trouble understanding some parts of these lines of code:

`fn_ = boost::bind(&CheckFeasibility, this, &world_, _1, _2, _3 );`

`if (robot_state_->setFromIK(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, fn_ ))`

What is the purpose of `this` in the first line and when and how are the arguments of `CheckFeasibility` determined and passed to it?

Here is what the `CheckFeasibility` function looks like (I have omitted the data types of the arguments):

`bool CheckFeasibility(*world, *state, *grp, *values)`

Thank you

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::bind`, or nowadays `std::bind`, is used to *bind* some arguments to a function. The result is a function that takes less arguments (and returns the same thing).

The line of code in your example is basically equivalent to:

```
const auto fn_ = [this, &world](auto&& arg1, auto&& arg2, auto&& arg3) {
  return checkFeasibility(&world, arg1, arg2, arg3);
};
```

The arguments to `bind` are the function that you want to call, followed by all the arguments to the function. You can set them to fixed values or use the placeholders `_1`, `_2` etc. to leave them out for now and pass them when you call the resulting function. The resulting function thus expects exactly as many arguments as the number of placeholders you use. You could also specify them in a different order to reorder arguments.

For member functions, their implicit first argument is the `this` pointer, so here the second argument to `bind` is the object on which the function is called.

In your example, the callback function passed to `setFromIK` is expected to take three parameters, but the authors only have a more general function that takes five (`this` and `world` are the extra ones.) So they make a more specific function out of this general function for which two parameters are already fixed. This is called *Currying*.

Note that the C++ Core Guidelines recommend to use lambdas over bind, if possible. It is often more readable and possibly even faster because it's easier for the compiler to optimize, e.g. by inlining the called function. But this depends on the exact code and compiler.

Comment: Thank you! So, at what point were the values of `*state`, `*grp` and `*values` determined? I don't see them created or assigned anywhere in the code and they are used in the function. Thanks.

Comment: @bbaalleerr22 They are passed where `fn_` is called, so look for `fn_(..., ..., ...)`

Comment: @bbaalleerr22 • for modern C++ (C++11 and later), my recommendation is to use lambdas and/or lambdas-with-closures rather than `bind`.

Comment: Thanks Felix! You've been helpful. Unfortunately I did a search and I can't find `fn_(...` anywhere in the code. Perhaps `robot_state_->setFromIK` calls it internally. I will see if I find anything in the moveit documentation. Thanks.

Comment: I checked the documentation but still didn't find where `fn_` was called. 
 http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_core/html/robot__state_8cpp_source.html#l01292

Comment: `setFromIK` takes a parameter `const GroupStateValidityCallbackFn& constraint`, for which you pass in  `fn_` as the argument. And `constraint` is actually called in 3 places in this file, e.g. in `setFromIKSubgroups`.

Comment: Nitpick: the function returned from bind can be called with any number of arguments > 3, so it's more equivalent to `[this, &world](auto&& arg1, auto&& arg2, auto&& arg3, auto...){ return checkFeasibility(&world, arg1, arg2, arg3); }`

Comment: Thanks @FelixDombek!! I was expecting it to be called under the `setFromIK` definition

Comment: @Caleth True, and also I forgot the `std::forward` which I hope bind does...

Answer (score 0):

`boost::bind` gives you a function that maps its arguments to call another function and then optionally adds some it already knows. It's part of the standard now, so you can read some more at [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/).